# Sorting Array using usort?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am having problem trying to sort an array - I want all the IsOpen = 1 to appear at the top?

Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Isopen] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Isopen] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Isopen] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Isopen] => 1
        )
```

Code:

```
   function cmp($a, $b) {
        if ($a['Isopen'] >= $b['Isopen']) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    usort($data['rowResult'], "cmp");
```

I don't understand what does $a and $b mean, I had a look at the PHP documentation - information is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a and $b are the elements to compare:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['Isopen'] == $b['Isopen']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['Isopen'] > $b['Isopen']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: It appear all the $b['Isopen'] = 1 is at the bottom. Should other way around

Comment: are you sure you copy that function? check the **<** on the last return, in case you put **>**

Comment: Changed from `<` to `>` fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

The cmp funciton should return 0, -1 (or less than zero) or 1 (or greater than zero).

- zero if the two values are equal.
- greater than zero if the value form a is higher.
- less than zero if the value from b is higher.

for the comparison of the two values you may use php function strcmp

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a['Isopen'], $b['Isopen']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
        if ($a['Isopen'] == $b['Isopen']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['Isopen'] >  $b['Isopen']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

this will makes  Isopen = 1 at the end of the array if you want it at the begging make this

```
 function cmp($a, $b) {
            if ($a['Isopen'] == $b['Isopen']) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($a['Isopen'] <  $b['Isopen']) ? -1 : 1;
        }
```

Comment: To make Isopen at the top, I have to change it to:    `return ($a['Isopen'] < $b['Isopen']) ? 1 : -1;`  seem to work

Answer (score 0):

in this example $a[] and $b[] are two arrays that are handed to the function named 'cmp'. it compares the value of 'Isopen' in two different arrays.

check out the documentation on user defined functions
http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

and how to properly use usort()
[http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)

Answer (score 0):

The sorting aglorithm is a [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Essentially, it compares array entities at a time to determining their ordering. To see a step by step example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Step-by-step_example

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when he can use library function? And why the slow bubble sort of all algorithms?

Comment: @Erbureth Who said anything about reinventing the wheel? I simply provided documentation on how the sort is actually performed, i.e., the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your function *cmp* is not correct (see my example of correct use). Besides if you use php 5.3+ you can use anonymous functions like this:

```
usort($data['rowResult'], function($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['Isopen'] == $b['Isopen'])
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return $a['Isopen'] < $b['Isopen'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```